# Map character to X and Y in png - JAVA

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have this png image:

[image: character tile map]

and a string, say "Hello World". In order to map texture coords for LWJGL, I need to know the X and Y position of each 16x16 character in the PNG. I am completely lost on how one would do that.. Anyone?

Comment: Couldn't you just split the image?

Comment: You need to know the width/height of the titles, from this you can calculate pixel x/y of each title...because your tile map is uneven, you will either need to split into groups of even titles or create a lookup map

Comment: There are *3* character sets in the image (not all are complete alphabets). First decision is which one to use. Then, notice your statement "each 16x16 character" appears to be untrue.

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like this:

```
final int spriteWidth = 16;
final int spriteHeight = 16;

 ...

int rows = sheet.getWidth()/spriteWidth;
int cols = sheet.getHeight()/spriteHeight;

BufferedImage sheet = ImageIO.read(new File("\\a\b\\c\\sprite_file.png"));
BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];
for(int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        images[y * x] = sheet.getSubImage(x * rows, y * cols, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
    }
 }
```

- Then make final int variables like so:

  `public static final int SPRITE_0 = 0;`
   `public static final int SPRITE_1 = 1;`
  `...`

and access like so:

`images[SPRITE_0]`

---

Edit:

taking into consideration what @MadProgrammer has stated, I would recommend that you split the image into two parts, like so:

[image: spritesheet]

**(split at the red line)**

and then simply altering the code to handle the two different parts. The code will remain the same except for the variables `final int spriteWidth` and `final int spriteHeight`. I'm sure you can handle this yourself.

---

Edit 2:

if you just want the x and y co-ords of the top left corner of each sprite, do the following:

```
final int spriteWidth = 16;
final int spriteHeight = 16;

...

int rows = sheet.getWidth()/spriteWidth;
int cols = sheet.getHeight()/spriteHeight;
Point[] spriteTopLeftCorner = new Point[rows * cols];
for(int y = 0; y < sheet.getHeight(); y += spriteHeight) {
    for(int x = 0; x < sheet.getWidth(); x += spriteWidth) {
        spriteTopLeftCorner[y/spriteHeight * x/spriteWidth] = new Point(y, x);
    }
}
```

you would ofcourse still need to make variables representing each sprite's index in this `Array`, otherwise you wouldn't know what sprite you are taking out.

- Do this like so:

  `public static final int SPRITE_0 = 0;`
   `public static final int SPRITE_1 = 1;`
  `...`

- and access like so:

  `spriteTopLeftCorner[SPRITE_0];`

Comment: I don't need a BufferedImage as a result, i need the top-corner x and y of each character 16x16 square.